# Cloning ListBuffer immutable issue Scala

Tags: scala, list, copy, immutability, mutable

I have a `var x` of type `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]` in which I am cloning using the function `clone` and setting to another `var y`, I then use the function `update` on this new `var y` to update the contents, but when I check the original contents of `var x` it is the same as `var y`? Why is this? What am I doing wrong? Is their a workaround? I am trying to achieve a copy of  ListBuffer that I can modify without changing the original contents of the initial ListBuffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`clone` only makes a shallow copy, you need a deep copy:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> var a = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 2), ListBuffer(3,4))
a: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))


scala> var b = a.clone
b: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))

scala> b(0)(0) = 100

scala> a
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(100, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))

scala> b
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(100, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))

scala> var c = a.clone.map(_.clone)
c: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(100, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))

scala> c(0)(0) = 1000

scala> c
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1000, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))

scala> a
res4: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer(100, 2), ListBuffer(3, 4))
```

Comment: To achieve a deep copy, is `var c = a.clone.map(_.clone)` to ideal way?

Comment: For simple things like this I would say yes, for something more complicated or deeper you might want a fancier solution (like [this](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning)?).